# Condition on isomorphism to opposite category

Tags: category-theory

I've been very interested in when a category $C$ is isomorphic to it's opposite category. Playing around, I conjecture that the following condition is necessary and sufficient for a category $C$ with zero-morphisms:

- For all objects $O$ in $C$ and morphisms $f$ where $\operatorname{src}(f)=O$, if both objects exist then $O/\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is isomorphic to $f(O)$.

Where the concepts of images, quotients, kernels are extended via universal properties.

Is this true? Does every "self-dual" category with zero-morphisms have this condition and is every category with this condition self-dual?

Comment: For clarity's sake, what do you mean by src$(f)$?

Comment: @Matt The object which is the source of the arrow $f$ - not sure if there's a better name for it, but if there is feel free to edit.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you not extend the usual notions by way of universal properties?

Comment: @Matt: "Source and target" is terminology alternate to "domain and codomain". IMO, the former is preferable in every regard except for the fact it lacks widespread familiarity.

Comment: It was relatively obvious what was meant, indeed. I just wanted to be sure, and also clear up potential confusion for others.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's true - let me edit and make things a little clearer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Is this edit clearer? I'm really only talking about categories where these are well-defined, so I have no trouble adding the zero-morphism condition.

Comment: The category of abelian groups certainly satisfies your condition; but according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662672/show-ab-the-category-of-abelian-groups-is-not-equivalent-to-its-opposite-categ it is not even equivalent to its opposite category.

Comment: And even if your condition is satisfied : imagine a category with no quotients, kernels, images; that isn't isomorphic to its opposite category ?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition doesn't characterize self-dual categories, and in fact it is not even self-dual : indeed it holds in the category of groups but not in its dual.

Indeed, the first isomorphism theorem tells you precisely that for any group $G$ and group homomorphism $f:G\to H$, we have an isomorphism $G/\ker(f)\cong f(G)$, so the property holds. Now the quotient $G\to G/\ker(f)$ is the cokernel of the kernel of $f$; thus the dual property would be that the factorisation $G\to \ker(\operatorname{coker}(f))$ of $f$ through the kernel of its cokernel is an epimorphism, and thus surjective. But the cokernel of $f$ is the quotient by the *normal closure* $\widehat{f(G)}$ of its image; thus if the image of $f$ is not normal in $H$, the factorisation $G\to \ker(\operatorname{coker}(f))$ will be equal to the surjection $G\to f(G)$ followed by a proper injection $f(G)\to \widehat{f(G)}$, and thus it will not be surjective.

In particular, this tells you that even though it satisfies your condition, $\mathbf{Grp}$ is not equivalent to its dual.

Comment: And for the other direction, $\mathbf{Rel}$ is pointed and isomorphic to its opposite, but I don't think it has kernels or images.